# Go lang While loop

Tags: go

- I want to extract all the autoscaling groups from AWS
- AWS provides response in multiple pages with `NextToken` pointing to next page. So need keep looking for `NextToken` and pull the group names
- If there is no `NextToken`, then quit.

In python, I do:

```
import boto3
import pprint

session = boto3.session.Session(region_name='us-west-2')
client = session.client('autoscaling')

resp = client.describe_auto_scaling_groups()
pprint.pprint(resp)

while 'NextToken' in resp:
    resp = client.describe_auto_scaling_groups(NextToken=resp['NextToken'])          
    pprint.pprint(resp)
```

I followed similar logic in [[image]go](/questions/tagged/go) and came up with below code:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/aws"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/aws/session"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/service/autoscaling"
)

func main() {
    sess, err := session.NewSession(&aws.Config{Region: aws.String("us-west-2")})

    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Failed to create session: ", sess)
        return
    }

    svc := autoscaling.New(sess)
    params := &autoscaling.DescribeAutoScalingGroupsInput{}
    resp, err := svc.DescribeAutoScalingGroups(params)

    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Something Went wrong")
        return
    }

    fmt.Println(resp)

    for {
        if resp.NextToken == nil {
            fmt.Println("No more pages left")
            break
        }

        params := &autoscaling.DescribeAutoScalingGroupsInput{
            NextToken: aws.String(*resp.NextToken),
        }
        resp, err := svc.DescribeAutoScalingGroups(params)

        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println("Something Went wrong")
            return
        }

        fmt.Println(resp)
    }
}
```

**QUESTION:** My [[image]go](/questions/tagged/go) code goes to the 2nd page and then keep looping over the same 2nd page. It does not proceed to 3rd page (when there is `NextToken` in `resp`) or it does not quit (when there is no `NextToken` in `resp`).

Seeking help on my [[image]go](/questions/tagged/go) code. I am learning [[image]go](/questions/tagged/go)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your inner `resp` seems to [shadow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing) your original `resp`. Try this inside the **inner** `for` loop (`:=` replaced with `=`):

```
resp, err = svc.DescribeAutoScalingGroups(params)
```

Comment: Thanks. If I declare `var err error` before the **outer** `resp` then code fails with error `err redeclared in this block`. If I declare `var err error` before **inner** `resp`, then there is no change in behavior.

Comment: @slayedbylucifer So this doesn't help? What if you simply replace `:=` with `=` in the loop?

Comment: Hi @Ainar-G, Replacing `:=` with `=` errors out saying `undefined: resp`.

Comment: @slayedbylucifer Are you sure you're replacing `:=` in the **inner** resp?

Comment: Oh. Sorry. My Bad. Yes, It is working. In **inner** loop I replaced `:=` to `=` and it worked. Many Thanks. Does `:=` in inner loop means I am defining same `resp` variable (which is already defined earlier) one more time and hence it was misbehaving ? Would you mind explaining this in brief words or point me to any documentation. Thank you !!

Comment: @slayedbylucifer Yes, writing `a, b := foo()` is basically the same as `var a, b = foo()`. So you're defining new variables with it. In this case you defined a new variable `resp`, which is different from `resp` that you checked in the `if` above it. It's a common gotcha with `:=`.